# Javascript Function won't work as suppose to do after a few calls

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build this app which will generate a random question from two arrays of data: `country` and `questions`. So I want to query that question to the HTML and then the user answer the question through a text input and then check if the answer is correct. After a few calls the app works fine, but sometimes won't work as suppose... For example: for the question "Which is the capital of Romania?" the correct answer should be "bucuresti" but for a reason I don't understand the correct answer to pass the question is actually "romania". I'm guessing ther is a problem whit my `if/else` statement in the `chechAnswer()`function

```js
Array.prototype.random = function (length) {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*length)];
};

var country = [
      {name:"romaniei", capital: "bucuresti"},
      {name: "bulgariei", capital: "sofia"}
    ],
    questions = [
      "Care este capitala ",
      " este capitala carei tari?"
    ];

document.querySelector('input').onclick= function() {
  var q,
      chosen_country = country.random(country.length),
      chosen_question = questions.random(questions.length);
      
    cc = chosen_country;
    cq = chosen_question;
  if(chosen_question == questions[0]){
    q = chosen_question + chosen_country.name + "?";
  } else if(chosen_question == questions[1]){
    q =  chosen_country.capital + chosen_question;
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#que').innerHTML= q;
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true; 

};
 checkAnswer = function() {
     var intrebare;
  var answer = document.myform.ans.value;         
     if(cq == questions[0] && answer == cc.capital){
         alert("corect");
         document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false; 
     }else if (cq == questions[1] && answer == cc.name) {
         alert("corect");
         document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false; 
     }else {
         alert("incorect");
     }
};
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Generate question">
  <div id="que">Intrebare:</div>
   <input type="text" id="ans">
  <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="checkAnswer()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an invalid boolean check (or, rather, it wont do what you're expecting it to do!):

```
if(answer === (cc.name || cc.capital)){
```

That should be

```
if(answer === cc.name || answer === cc.capital){
```

Notwithstanding the above, your logic is still a bit off, when choosing a question, you determine whether you want to use the contry or the city as part of the question:

```
cc = chosen_country;
  if(chosen_question == questions[0]){
    q= chosen_question + chosen_country.name + "?";
  } else if(chosen_question == questions[1]){
    q=  chosen_country.capital + chosen_question;
  }
```

<sup><sup>(Asside: The above code makes picking a random question a little obsolete)</sup></sup>

However, when testing the answer, there is no such check, which means the question "What is the capital of romaniei" will accept an answer "romaniei" or "bucuresti".

Comment: The logic of his code seems wrong, even after this fix. If the question was 'What is the capital of romania?' it would still allow the answer romania to be correct ! He should instead have a single property "correctAnswer" which he should check in the method.

Comment: Does that mean that 'sofia' would be seen as the right answer for the question "sofia is the capital of what country?"?  It feels like you might want to know which question was asked (or at least it's structure) to know whether or not you should check against name or capital.

Comment: Oh... i get it now... But I have a question, why do you use double ) at the end of the statment? And yes... my logic is kinda bad, I just assume the user would input just a capital name just when asked about a capital and a country when asked about a country. Well, this is the thing i hate about programming because it involves a lot of logics, even if they are simple I'm just bad at it sometimes. I have in mind some grate apps to build but my brain won't help me to build them because i fail at simple logic when building just as you seen, lol. Will my logis evolve during my learnings?

Comment: @IulianConstantinRedinciuc - The extra `)` was a mistake when I copied your code. And yes, programming like everything gets easier with practice ;)

Comment: @Jamiec - I've changed my code a bit so would take as argument the question first and then will compare if the answer is corect :) check the  edited code snipped. You helped me a lot in this, thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

The if statement in your `checkAnswer()` function is a little off.

It needs to be:

```
if(answer === cc.name || answer === cc.capital)
```

Your current code will not give you the expected results.

Also correct and incorrect are spelled wrong.